# Maximize the function $x+y$ on the closure of the unit ball

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

> Find the maximum of $\{x +y : (x,y) \in closure [B(0,1)] \}$. Here $B(0,1)=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$

I can't proceed in this as to how to maximize this value. Will it lie on the boundary of the unit ball or somewhere inside the ball?

Comment: Hint: the iso-($x+y)$ are parallel lines in direction $135°$.

Comment: Are we talking a unit ball in $\Bbb R$ or is this in $\Bbb R^2$ somehow?

Comment: @GregoryGrant  it is in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @YvesDaoust Why? I can't get it? What is iso?

Comment: @User23: "iso" is a Greek root meaning "equal", so here, lines that have a constant (equal) value along them for $x+y$.  To answer you question, yes, the maximum value will either lie on the boundary or somewhere "inside" the ball (more technically, the *interior* of the ball).  Use calculus to find out which.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Look at the level sets $C_k=\{(x,y)\mid x+y=k\}$. Note that your objective function has value $k$ on $C_k$.

What's the largest $k$ such that $C_k$ meets $\overline{B(0,1)}$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

The point (0,0) lies in your ball. So your set contains 0 + 0 = 0.

It also contains 0 + 1 = 1 since (0,1) lies on the closure of B(0,1).

So what other values does your set have? And where is the biggest?

Comment: @PhilipHamilton also we have points of type (1,0), (-1,0).For all these $x +y=1$ or -1. We have $(1/sqrt 2,1/sqrt 2)$ in the ball for which $x+y=sqrt 2$. But how do we ensure which is the maximum value ?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient

Comment: If you're in a class on multivariate calculus, then gradient has probably come up.  The equation you're trying to optimize is just $z = x + y$